# Does vim provide tiered intellisense support through phpdoc?

Tags: vim, ide, intellisense, phpdoc

The one thing I really miss in vim is a tiered intellisense support, just like we have one in PHP Eclipse.

For example:

```
/**
 * Get the config object
 *
 * @return Config
 */
public function getConfig()
{
    return $this->_config;
}
```

I find this explicit return type setting very useful and time saving feature.

Do we have something similar in vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim by itself doesn't really have any intellisense...  Instead, it just provides autocompletion.  This means that Vim isn't aware of language, types, etc.  It just looks for strings that it can complete.

I'm not familiar with tiered intellisense, but you could try using the [Vim Intellisense](http://insenvim.sourceforge.net/) plugin.  It does have language-specific completion and type-checking.  It does not have direct support for PHP, but perhaps it will get you closer to your goal.

**EDIT** Using Vim's omnifunc, you can get function completion, but there is still no built-in type awareness.

Comment: As I know VIM Intellisense provides PHP-syntax and doesn't help in tiered intellisense at all. And looks like ctags couldn't solve this problem as well.

Comment: I'm a vim user.  I don't use eclipse or other IDE.  So I looked up tiered intellisense.  What I found, and this is for amusement only, is the poorest screencast ever.  There are enough classic coding mistakes here for a new drinking game.  Does intellisense make you so lazy that you forget the basics? Check out "Zend Studio Tutorial: Basic Intellisense" at http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-7549951996065462856#